# ZNC, Systemd, and Ubuntu 16.04.1 Server

Tags: boot, server, cron, systemd, init.d

I recently did a backup of my ZNC VPS, and did a clean install from 14.04.5 to 16.04.1 Server. The only major issue that I'm having so far, is moving from init.d to Systemd. ZNC just won't autoboot.

Things I've tried so far,

[Systemd](http://wiki.znc.in/Running_ZNC_as_a_system_daemon#systemd)

[Cron](http://wiki.znc.in/FAQ#How_can_I_restart_ZNC_automatically_.28in_case_of_a_machine_reboot.2C_crash.2C_etc..29.3F)

init.d

I've run everything under my user as sudo and still, it exits when called on and will not start automatically upon reboot. Starting ZNC manually however works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Add a cronjob entry to restart your server.

Look [here](http://wiki.znc.in/FAQ#How_can_I_restart_ZNC_automatically_.28in_case_of_a_machine_reboot.2C_crash.2C_etc..29.3F) for how to do that.

Comment: This is probably the correct answer (since the official wiki says so), but I hate the answer. It looks way to hacky fo my taste — it would not be particularly easy to maintain if all programs did it like this.